# Как узнать совместимость Iphone с xcode?

Tags: xcode, iphone

Добрый день!

**Xcode 8** позволяет ли запускать приложения на **настоящем Iphone 4** ? (просто симуляторы там есть начиная только с Iphone 5).

Или xcode 8 может запускать приложения на настоящем Iphone любой модели ?

Подскажите пожалуйста что-либо по данному поводу.

Заранее спасибо!

Жду вашего ответа.

Comment: на сколько мне ивсетно, не важно какой эмулятор, главное это что-бы режим совместимости с ios6 был и да вы можете использовать эмулятор от 4s они почти ничем не отличаются.

Comment: все на всем запускается. убедитесь, что deployment target подходящий

Comment: насколько я понял, я могу приобрести **старенький Iphone 4** и на этом реальном аппарате запускать приложения используя **xcode 8** ? :)